# Xbox driver for PS4 for mac?

Tags: games, driver, steam

I have a Dualshock 4 controller and can't play certain games like portal because there is no PS4 support. I heard on windows are drivers that trick the computer into thinking that the PS4 input is an xbox input but can't find ANY for apple. Is there a workaround or are there drivers for mac that allow me to do the same?

Comment: You should edit the question's title. It's not clear from reading it what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a button mapping issue. I haven't tested it so I'm not sure it answers your question but here's what I stumbled upon today:

> I used an app from the Mac App Store called, Joystick Mapper, although other apps are also available. This allows you to manually map each input from the DS4 to keyboard buttons on your Mac, effectively using the keyboard settings in games as your controls. For this example I mapped the inputs from my DS4 to the keyboard settings in Max Payne 3. If you look at the pictures below, you can see how I used the keyboard settings in the game to help me map the controller (click on the pictures to enlarge them).

http://www.backwardscompatible.co.uk/using-your-dual-shock-4-controller-on-a-macbook.html

The app is here: https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/joystick-mapper/id528183797?mt=12